# SPARQL's query doesn't give data

Tags: sparql

I've got a problem, I would like to retrieve data from a query in SPARQL in order to display this data on a HTML page but I can't get the data from this query.

Here is the SparQL query :

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT DISTINCT ?Titre ?Auteur ?Editeur ?Volumes
WHERE {
    ?Titre rdf:type dbo:Manga .
        ?Titre dbp:publisher res:Kadokawa_Shoten .
        ?Titre dbo:author ?Auteur .
        ?Titre dbp:publisher ?Editeur.
        ?Titre dct:subject dbc:Seinen_manga .
        ?Titre dbo:numberOfVolumes ?Volumes .
}
```

When I try to use it on [snorql](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia2%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+res%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3A%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3FTitre+%3FAuteur+%3FEditeur+%3FVolumes%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%09%3FTitre+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3AManga+.%0D%0A++++++++%3FTitre+dbp%3Apublisher+res%3AKadokawa_Shoten+.%0D%0A++++++++%3FTitre+dbo%3Aauthor+%3FAuteur+.%0D%0A++++++++%3FTitre+dbp%3Apublisher+%3FEditeur.%0D%0A++++++++%3FTitre+dct%3Asubject+dbc%3ASeinen_manga+.%0D%0A++++++++%3FTitre+dbo%3AnumberOfVolumes+%3FVolumes+.%0D%0A%7D), this query get the right data :
But when I try to use it on the [d3sparql](http://biohackathon.org/d3sparql/) library and try to display on a d3htmltable the data, it doesn't work.

Comment: Just replace `PREFIX dbpedia2:` with `PREFIX dbp:`.

Comment: I've just tried it on d3sparql.js on the htmltable, it didn't work

Comment: "SPARQL endpoint" must be `http://dbpedia.org/sparql`

Comment: Show the code where you use the d3sparql library.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks, i'm so dumb